# Airport Extreme Name Resolution

Tags: windows, airport, dns, active-directory

I have a little issue with my airport extreme. I'm using the device in my corporate network which has two DNS server for resolving intern and external names.

When I do an nslookup "public adresse" (such as www.google.com), everything works fine.

...But, when I try to resolve an internal name, for exemple bardo1, I get:

```
;;SERVFAIL reply from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX trying next server
;;connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

When I try nslookup internalservername my.internal.dns.server everything works thing.

Where is the problem ??? I don't get it.

Is it because apple uses a different way to resolve names then microsoft ?

How can I fix that on the router ? Not on client side...

```
My PC Config IP: 10.0.1.3/32 Gateway: 10.0.1.1 DNS: 10.0.1.1

Airport Extreme IP WAN: 172.16.1.117 DNS1: x.x.x.13 DNS2: x.x.x.45 domain: mydomain.local
```

Comment: I think I understand most of your question, but could you elaborate on how Microsoft relates to this? Are you using a Microsoft router or assuming that AirPort DNS emulates Microsoft Server DNS in some way?

Comment: We're using an microsoft environment, server and clients... Boss finds airport classic nice '^^. So I need to find a way to forward my 2 other dns.

I think i will declarate them staticly on his notebook, since he don't takes it off his office

Answer (score 1):

Apple's DNS resolution expects a tiered solution, so you will want to simply point the router and clients to the internal DNS.

That DNS will answer all queries for it's internal responses and refer/forward requests outside it's authority to the outside DNS of your choosing.

In short, you will either need to change your internal DNS or set up a third DNS to know what requests to handle internally and which externally as the AirPort wasn't designed to do that choosing for you.

Here's how you would [set up OS X server DNS to do forwarding](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x-server/managing-dns-using-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-server/) - it's a simple pane where you place the external addresses.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reponse... but we haven't OS X Server ;)

Comment: There is a [super user](http://superuser.com) site where you could ask how to set up windows dns to forward and link here for the airport details. It's been a while since I set up windows DNS, but it surely has this feature just link bind on unix / OS X does.

Comment: Similarly to OS X Server, go to the DNS Manager in Windows... Action | Properties... Forwarders tab, then under DNS Domain, click your domain. Under Selected domain's forwarder IP address list, type the IP address of a forwarder, then Add.

Answer (score -1):

Try swapping the order of the DNS servers on the AirPort Extreme.

Comment: At won't work long term - see my answer about having each DNS entry do a proper lookup and forward queries outside its domain to other DNS.